# Android onAnimationEnd called twice

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-animation

i have created a SLIDE UP animation on view and i am repeating this animation again onAnimationEnd but my onAnimationEnd fired twice  , i have checked it with counter at onAnimationEnd , i will post my code, you can check that the counter in onAnimationEnd will incremented twice at same time , I am starting the animation again in onAnimationEnd method , please guide me where i am doing wrong?

```
    private Animation animSlideUp;
        animSlideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.slide_up);
                // set animation listener
                animSlideUp.setAnimationListener(this);
                animSlideUp.setDuration(500);
                animSlideUp.setStartOffset(5000);

                tickerView.startAnimation(animSlideUp);

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            if (animation == animSlideUp) {
                ticker_counter++;
                Log.e("onAnimationEnd=", "ticker_counter="+ticker_counter);
                tickerView.startAnimation(animSlideUp);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

slide_up.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

    <scale
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.0"/>

</set>
LOGCAT

    11-19 17:06:54.375   E/onAnimationEnd=﹕ ticker_counter=1
    11-19 17:06:54.392   E/onAnimationEnd=﹕ ticker_counter=2
    11-19 17:06:59.912   E/onAnimationEnd=﹕ ticker_counter=3
    11-19 17:06:59.928   E/onAnimationEnd=﹕ ticker_counter=4
    11-19 17:07:05.453   E/onAnimationEnd=﹕ ticker_counter=5
    11-19 17:07:05.470   E/onAnimationEnd=﹕ ticker_counter=6
    11-19 17:07:10.991   E/onAnimationEnd=﹕ ticker_counter=7
    11-19 17:07:11.008   E/onAnimationEnd=﹕ ticker_counter=8
```

Comment: You are calling tickerView.startAnimation(animSlideUp); two times.... Please check your code and remove the unnecessory startanimation part...

Comment: i have to repeat the animation again so that's why i am calling the
tickerView.startAnimation(animSlideUp);

Comment: remove animSlideUp.setDuration(500); because u r already set it in xml...

Comment: done , but still the same issue

Comment: if you don't call startAnimation in the onAnimationEnd method, does the onAnimationEnd method still get called twice?

Comment: if i comment the startAnimation in the onAnimationEnd method , then it is not called twice, i am not able to repeat the animation SLIDE UP after every five seconds

Comment: try starting the next animation using post(new Runnable() { tickerView.startAnimation(); });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your animation to play once, you have to remove tickerView.startAnimation(animSlideUp); from the onAnimationEnd Method.
Avoid using xml animations, it's much easier in java code.
If you're trying to animate two properties :

```
PropertyValuesHolder pvhX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", 1.0f, 0);
PropertyValuesHolder pvhY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", 1.0f, 0);
ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(tickerView, pvhX, pvhY);
        animator.setDuration(500);
        animator.start();
```

In your case, you're only changing the scaleY value from 1.0 to 0, so use this :

```
ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tickerView, "scaleY",0);
animator.setDuration(500);
//To repeat twice if you want to
animator.setRepeatCount(1);
animator.start();
```

LinearInterpolator is used by default.

Repeat after every 5 sec

```
    final ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tickerView, "scaleY", 0);
    animator.setDuration(500);
    animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            ticker_counter++;
            animation.setStartDelay(5000);
            animator.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
        }
    });
    animator.start();
```

Comment: i want to repeat the animation SLIDE UP after every five seconds with COUNTER incrementing , like first time counter is 0 then animation starts counter increments to 1 in the setAnimationListener() method  and then so on . as you can see in mu code in onAnimationEnd() method

Comment: I updated my answer. Animation replays after 5 seconds

Answer (score 1):

I may found **the solution: post an runnable to restart the animation.**

In your case , in `OnAnimationEnd()` function, code like this:

```
 @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        if (animation == animSlideUp) {
            ticker_counter++;
            Log.e("onAnimationEnd=", "ticker_counter="+ticker_counter);
            tickerView.post(new Runnable(){ //post an runnable to start
                tickerView.startAnimation(animSlideUp);
            });

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and just setting `null` as listener of second animation worked for me.

```
setListener(null);
```

Example:

```
view.animate()
    .alpha(0F)
    .setDuration(200L)
    .setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

            view.animate()
                .alpha(1F)
                .setDuration(200L)
                .setListener(null)
                .start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
        }

    }).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I removed

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

from the xml file and it helped