# Android: onAnimationStart and onAnimationEnd are getting executed twice for custom LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-animation

I have searched before posting this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33803125/android-onanimationend-called-twice) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48354867/onanimationend-called-twice).

The questions are answered, but even though I used `ObjectAnimator` with `AnimatorListener` the problem still exists. Hence posting this question.

I have extended `LinearLayout` to create a custom view. While displaying this view in an activity, I have added fade in animation to show this. After animation for this view is completed which is `onAnimationEnd`, there is some business logic which has to be executed only once. Because of `onAnimationEnd` method executing twice, the application is crashing. The code is shown below.

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), animResource);
animation.setDuration(animDuration);
animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onAnimationStart: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onAnimationEnd: ");
        // my business logic goes here
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onAnimationRepeat");
    }
});
linearLayout.startAnimation(animation);
```

I observed the error log statements `onAnimationStart:` and `onAnimationEnd:` in `logcat` are getting displayed twice.

```
12-04 17:33:16.899 16980-16980/com.myapp E/Anim: onAnimationStart: android.view.animation.AnimationSet@87af0ac
12-04 17:33:17.229 16980-16980/com.myapp E/Anim: onAnimationEnd: com.myapp.views.CustomLinearLayout@518a944

12-04 17:33:17.690 16980-16980/com.myapp E/Anim: onAnimationStart: android.view.animation.AnimationSet@87af0ac
12-04 17:33:18.097 16980-16980/com.myapp E/Anim: onAnimationEnd: com.myapp.views.CustomLinearLayout@518a944
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: replace `Log.e(TAG, "onAnimationStart: ");` with `Log.e(TAG, "onAnimationStart: " + this);` what do you see now on the logcat?

Comment: I just see `onAnimationStart: Animation@some_memory_address`.

Comment: and what is that `some_memory_address`???

Comment: Yeah. I tried with both. But got same issue. It is `Animation` object's hash code. For example, `Animation@14da7d6`. Sorry, I was wrong before.

Comment: post the whole logcat output

Comment: It looks messy in comments section. I'll update the question.

Comment: add `+ this` in `onAnimationEnd` too - now i see some `CustomLinearLayout`, what is a value of  `animDuration`?

Comment: @pskink, Already added. Please check

Comment: this code block has not any problem .the problem happens some where else .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured out and solved the issue.

I thought the view is ready to visible to end user in `onLayout` method of view lifecycle. So, I have override `onLayout` method and kept the animation logic in it.

```
@Override
public void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    if (changed) {
        // Added animation logic
    }
}
```

When I'm debugging the code, I found `onLayout` method is getting invoked twice in my case. After googling it, I found out that it gets invoked multiple times to position this view according to all of it's parent views.

If `if (changed)` condition is removed, it's getting invoked 5 times.

I removed the animation logic from `onLayout` method and handled it activity itself. Now, it is working as expected.

So, I learned starting or setting animation to views is not suggestible inside `onLayout` method.

I hope What I understood is correct. Please correct me, if my understanding is wrong.